# How to fix issue with php send comment as json response?

Tags: php

I have a function that needs to return a simple json response.

```
        public function index(){

            $users = [
                [
                    "name" => "adam",
                    "age" => 20
                ]
            ];

            echo json_encode($users, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

        }
```

I have also have header for `content type` in my `index.php` file

```
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

But when I have a simple get request, the server also sends all the comments with `<!-- -->` with the json response. If I make a request so that the above `index` function gets invoked, the response will look something like this:

```
<!-- 
    It looks at the url and pulls out information to create a array and decides what to load
 -->

 <!-- 
    Super class for every other controllers
    Base controller
    Loads modals and views
-->

<!--
    PDO database class
    Model is going to use this class to interact with the database
 -->

[
    {
        "name": "samman",
        "age": 20
    }
]
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: JSON doesn't support html comments nor any type of comments.

Comment: @PavelTřupek yeah. But I have multiple files with comments. When I echo a json encoded data like I did above I want, the response to only contain that json data, not the comments. How can I avoid sending those comments?

Comment: You can use `echo  preg_replace('/<!--.*?-->/s', '', $str);` to remove html comments from $str

Comment: @PavelTřupek Thank you. It turns out I made a silly mistake. I could have simply put the comments inside the php tags but I had them outside.